# Visual C++ - Windows Form Control Library Projects - Compilation Type?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

if i make Windows Form Control Library Projects in VC++ will they be compiled as CLR or native EXEs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows Forms, then you're using .NET (and compiling with `/clr` if you're using Managed C++ or C++/CLI to write the code).

You can always find out whether you are compiling a managed library or executable by opening the project Property Pages (right click the project, select Properties):  on the Configuration Properties:  General page, there is an option "Common Language Runtime Support" that tells you whether you are compiling for the CLR.

Comment: i am a C# developer, just decided to move to C++ because i want to want native code no run time requiring and the first thing that scared me that there were all the types of C++ Projects.. i don't know what does what.. and i want the form designer view like i used to have in VC#. tell me what to do

Comment: i tried the Win32 Application but that doesn't have like a form designer view

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question, sorry.